# ExtJS 4: no method getName() on Ext.Base

Tags: extjs, extjs4

```
models: ['Foo'],
...
onEvent: function(args) {
    var foo = this.getFooModel().create(...);
    console.log(foo);
    console.log(foo.getName());
},
...
```

I'm getting an `Object [object Object] has no method 'getName'` error. Using Chrome's inspector, I see that `foo` has `$className: 'App.model.Foo'` and `modelName: 'App.model.Foo'` attached to `foo`'s `__proto__`. Inspecting further down the prototype chain, the object with `$className: 'Ext.Base'` indeed does not have a `getName` method..

Am I missing something?

Doc's reference of `Ext.data.Model.getName`: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-static-method-getName

Comment: and I don't want to have to use `__proto__.modelName` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a static method which can not be called on an instance of a model.

In your case, `this.getFooModel().getName()` should give the class name.

Comment: Is there a way to access the model from the record? i.e. foo.METHOD.getName() -> class name?

Comment: [Ext.getClassName](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext-method-getClassName)(foo) can give you the class name.  You may also be interested in looking at [Ext.getClass](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext-method-getClass). The first one gives the class name and the second one gives the reference to class which you can use to instantiate more objects

Comment: Don't know how I missed those.. Thanks for your time!